# How do I use a parameter in a windows git alias?

Tags: git

I have the following alias in git under Windows:

```
ss = \"!git stash save $1\"
```

If I enter `git ss abc` in git bash I get:

`expansion of alias 'ss' failed; '!git stash save $1' is not a git command`

How can I get this to work?

Comment: The "$1" would be replaced by the first parameter IF your alias launched an ad hoc bash function, but it's not the case. But as phd answered, you don't even need a parameter here, as your parameter is at the end and won't be affected by alias expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last parameter for an alias can be simply omitted:

```
ss = "!git stash save"
```

For more complex parameterization see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+alias+parameters

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had tried this but it must have been slightly different